# Big Decimal array not sorting 0 and 000.000

Tags: java, arrays, bigdecimal

I was solving a java *HackerRank* problem in which I had to sort an array consisting decimal numbers using `BigDecimal` class in descending order. The solution works fine except for one case in which 0 and 000.000 comes. Now as they are equal, the problem tells us not keep them in the same order of their occurrence, but it is not happening.

My Code:

```java
    import java.io.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class Solution {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = input.nextInt();
            String [] array = new String[n];
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                array[i] = input.next();
            }
            String temp;
            for(int i= array.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
                    if(new BigDecimal(array[i]).compareTo(new BigDecimal(array[j]))>0){
                        temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }          
        }
    }
```

Sample Input :
`9`   ---> the size of array

1. -100
2. 50
3. 0
4. 56.6
5. 90
6. 0.12
7. .12
8. 02.34
9. 000.000

Comment: Have you tried 2 and 2.000, for example?
This may be because one is integer and the other is double. 
I would try to evaluate the value and multiply with 1.0 in order to convert it from integer to double

Comment: @matt please elaborate on second line.

Comment: Instead of having a Scanner and some input just `String [] array = { "-100", "50", "0", "56.6", "90", "0.12", ".12", "02.34", "000.000" };` That way it is the same every time and we don't have to replicate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is **stability of sort**. You should select a stable sort algorithm.
[Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is such one.

```
String temp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0
        && new BigDecimal(array[j - 1]).compareTo(new BigDecimal(array[j])) < 0; j--) {
        temp = array[j - 1];
        array[j - 1] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

output:

```
[90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100]
```

Comment: Your output is wrong...

Comment: @Renis1235  Why is the output wrong? I think the numbers are in descending order and the condition of same order of occurence for same numbers is also satisfied.

Comment: @AdityaW the author changed the code and the output. Before it was not correct. Check the edits.

Answer (score 1):

I changed quite a few things in your code. Take a look at it.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = input.nextInt(); // getting the size

List<BigDecimal> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // Creating a list that holds our BigDecimals
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    double tmp = input.nextDouble(); // Getting the value as a Double and not as a string. It makes no sense to parse the string into a number later again
    numbers.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(tmp)); // Adding the double value as a BigDecimal
}

numbers.sort(BigDecimal::compareTo); // Sorting the list through the help of .compareTo() function

for (BigDecimal s : numbers)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Try to avoid strings when you take input from the user, you should force number input and not get some gibberish and then try to parse it, it will lead to problems later, it is better to handle wrong input at the moment it comes in.